# Write with several threads to a list and read it with an other

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi I got a problem with multithreading.
What I'm trying to do is getting some data with http requests. Currently I want to get data from 3 webservers. I'm using the threading module in python.

What I want to do now is write the data into an array and sort it.

```
Thread0 writes data to array[0]
Thread1 writes data to array[1]
Thread2 writes data to array[2]
```

This happens only when the data fetched from the webserver has changed.
A thread4 should copy that array when it has changed and sort it and do some processing on the **copy** afterwards.

This is my plan. How can I do this without blocking other thread's write actions and how can i assure that the data is not inconsistant when I read it.

Here is how far I have gotten with that idea.

Here is the module for one thread:

```
import threading

class http_fetcher(threading.Thread):
     _idx_of_list = []

     def set_idx(self,idx)
         self._idx_of_list = idx

     def run(self)
         global my_list

         #some http fetching stuff

         old_data = []

         if old_data != actual_data:
             old_data = actual_data
             my_list[self._idx_of_list] = actual_data
```

and here is the calling main program

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = []
    thread1 = http_fetcher()
    thread1.set_idx(1)
    thread1.start()

    thread2 = http_fetcher()
    thread2.set_idx(2)
    thread2.start()

    thread3 = http_fetcher()
    thread3.set_idx(3)
    thread3.start()
```

So far I have not worked on the reading site.
What do you think?
Writing to different indexes of a list should be thread safe or am I wrong?
But how do I signalize another thread that the list values have changed?
Currently I get an error
"NameError: global name 'my_list' is not defined"
Why that?

I hope some of you can help and finds this interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue

you may use Queue module to exchange information safely between multiple threads.
There is a good example at the end of module description.

Comment: Ok thanks for that I had a look at queues. As far as I understand the concept I'm synchronizing at the end of a queue. But what I want and I guess I forgot this is to run my 3 threads over and over (enclosed in a "while True" lopp and want to access the array they are creating without beeing blocked so long. Queues seems to be more like a list with tasks that threads work on until they are finished. But I don't want them to finish... Is there no better way? THe problem is, if one webserver sends the answer a lot later than the others do then I#m blocked for that time. I don't want this